# Residual plot for multiple linear regression

Tags: r, regression

Is it correct to put the predicted values on the x axis and residuals on the y axis? Like so:

```
attach(cars)
#Extra variable
cars$variable <- 1:50

regressor <- lm(dist~speed+variable)

cars$predicted.dist <- predict(regressor)

#plot predicted dist against residuals from the other 2 variables
plot(cars$predicted.dist, resid(regressor))
```

If this is ok and I was to split the data into test and training sets, I would run this procedure on the training set (before predicting values on the test set), correct?

Comment: A residual plot is a plot of residuals (y axis) vs. independent variables (x axis). So you should consider the independent variables instead of the predicted values on the x-axis.

Comment: There are circumstances where this makes sense, for example I have used this plot when regressing to the lowest relative error rather than the lowest absolute error.

Comment: @AhmadBazzi Yeah that works for 1 independent variable, but what if I have a bunch of them, then it can't be plotted as it requires 4 or more dimensions, right?